# Plot timeseries rgb values from a data.frame using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

R gurus,

I have a time-series data of RGB values from daily satellite imagery. I would like to plot daily variations in colors.

```
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(17911:17942, origin = "1970-01-01"),
                  red = sample(0:255, 32), 
                  green = sample(0:255, 32), 
                  blue = sample(0:255, 32))
```

I would like to see something like the following. I have tried ggplot raster plot but no success so far.

[image]

Your time and support is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option for plotting the rgb values, relying on `scale_fill_identity`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(date, y = 1)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = rgb(red, green, blue, maxColorValue = 255))) +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]

I don't know what the y-values should be, but the `rgb` in combination with the scale should work for the colours.